# Not Installed Error in Osclass

Tags: osclass

Please Note : I have well searched the Problem on official forums of Osclass and there is no appropriate problem.

The website name is http://www.eventspanda.com

OsClass has a serious bug, my website is fully developed and working most of times, but sometimes it says this error page in middle of nowhere :-

OsClass Error >> OSClass isn't installed. Need more help?

and after sometime, the website starts working normally. It is very frustrating.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Osclass are you running?

That could be that your MySQL server isn't available at the moment, but IIRC, in newer version it display a message about not being able to connect to the MySQL server. Could you please check the error log?

https://doc.osclass.org/Debug_PHP_errors
https://doc.osclass.org/Debug_SQL_queries

Comment: Thanks a lot. My Problem was resolved now. It was due to two different nameservers problem. And the Installation was not done correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The error above is due to a failed connection to your MySQL server, without connection to the MySQL server, the Osclass pages, can't be rendered.
On shared server environment MySQL servers are restarted automatically after critical security patches and upgrades.

**Solution:** Notify your web hosting company about the error they will sort you out.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, changing hosting company helps to resolve issue in fastest way.
Simply it means your MySQL databse went down or connection does not temporary work - so Osclass thinks it was not yet installed.